# How to create a sticky footer in an Angular2 app?

Tags: css, angular, sticky-footer

A sticky footer sticks to the bottom of a web page regardless of how much content the footer has. This is a solved problem if you use *FlexBox* commands in the web page's CSS stylesheet. All modern browsers support *FlexBox*.

However, using Angular2 to build a web app, I am unable to apply the simplest of the *FlexBox* commands! The footer does not stick to the bottom! Here's my [plunker to demonstrate the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/qNeimneBm4IrfeAG2HU1?p=preview).

In the plunker app, `style.css` contains a very simple *Flexbox* commands and it works - just simply replace the content of `index.html` with `index1.html` and see how the sticky footer is working great without Angular being present. With Angular2 app, I am using the same `style.css` so I added the the following template to the app, clearly marking the CSS classes `main` and `footer` as follows.

```
<div class="main">
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <h3> this is footer </h3>
</footer>
```

However, the footer never sticks.

Has anyone been able to solve this issue in Angular2? Does Angular2 have another way to provide sticky footer?

Any thoughts and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are defining the `site` div as the flex container and targeting `footer` as a flex item, but when you introduce the angular `my-app` element, `footer` is no longer a child of `site` (it is a child of `my-app` and thus a grandchild of `site`).

flex items need to be children of the flex container.

Comment: ah ok thanks @SimonFox! So can I style `my-app` in style.CSS as follows?

    `my-app {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}`

I added this to style.css. In addition I had the following in style.css.

    `html {
 height: 100%;
}`

`.main {
   flex: 1;
}`

However, the footer is still not sticky. It appears right below <router-outlet>, leaving a large white space between it and the bottom of page.

Comment: I got this to work. I modified `html { height: 100%; }` to `html, body { height: 100%; }`. I think html is not even needed here. Thanks @Simon for pointing out all angular directives are children of the root directive my-app. Now, I have `<body>` with child `<my-app>` with children `<div main>` and `<footer>` and the flexbox rules are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Include footer CSS in your code.

```html
<body>
  <header style="min-height: 255px;">
  </header>

  <article style="padding-bottom: 60px; width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;">
    Body text goes here.
  </article>

  <footer style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; height: 60px; background-color: black;">
    Copyright information
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Few problems with your suggestion (1) I'm specifically looking for a solution using Angular2 framework. If you look at my plunker demo, you will see how the flexbox CSS seems to have no effect in Angular2 app. I am looking for any solution as long as it is in Angular2 app (2) your footer CSS has a fixed height. I need the footer height to be dynamic. Using my plunker demo, if you simply replace the content of index.html with index1.html, I already have a better solution. Again, what I need is the Angular2 solution to this problem.
Thanks though for helping..

Answer (score 0):

you can create footer component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './app-footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements  {

}
```

and in the app.component.html add the footer under router-outler tag

```
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just by wrapping `<router-outlet>` and `<app-footer>` in `<div>` is not going to solve the issue at hand. Where in your code is guaranteeing the footer stickiness? It's all about knowing how to style the CSS, especially by using flex CSS and you have not shown that in your solution. Anyways, I have solved the problem but thanks for trying to help:)